# How call method validation for formGroup Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have form:

```
this.changePasswordForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'passwordNew': ['', ValidationService.passwordValidator], matchingPasswords('passwordNew', 'passwordNewConfirmation')(this)]]
});
```

And my custom validation function that I try to call:

```
export function matchingPasswords(passwordKey: string, confirmPasswordKey: string) {
  return (group: FormGroup): {
    [key: string]: any
  } => {
    let password = group.controls[passwordKey];
    let confirmPassword = group.controls[confirmPasswordKey];

    if (password.value !== confirmPassword.value) {
      return {
        mismatchedPasswords: true
      };
    }
  }
}
```

How to pass current form inside `matchingPasswords`? I tried to use `this`:

```
'passwordNewConfirmation')(this)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ValidatorFn function accepts current control as an argument. You can use that to access form group.

```ts
export interface ValidatorFn {
    (c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null;
}
```

and your function would look like this:

```ts
export function matchingPasswords(passwordKey: string, confirmPasswordKey: string) {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {
    [key: string]: any
  } => {
    if(!control.parent){
     return null;
    }
    let group = control.parent;
    let password = group.controls[passwordKey];
    let confirmPassword = group.controls[confirmPasswordKey];

    if (password.value !== confirmPassword.value) {
      return {
        mismatchedPasswords: true
      };
    }
  }
}
```

When registering, `this` won't be necessary:

```ts
this.changePasswordForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'passwordNew': ['', [ValidationService.passwordValidator, matchingPasswords('passwordNew', 'passwordNewConfirmation')]]
});
```

Comment: There is no `AbstractFormControl` in imports, only `AbstractControl`

Comment: Sorry, it should be `AbstractControl`. Updated.

Comment: I get this error: `ERROR Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.`